# Adjust table generation and request to generate table in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Could help me with two small problems in the code below?

The first thing is that I'm not able to show the information in the table that I generate. The idea is to show the information corresponding to my `Test` database, but it doesn't appear. The second thing is that when I run the APP, the table is already generated, however this is strange, since in `data_subset` I insert `req(input$daterange1)`.

Executable code below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

Test <- structure(list(date2 = c("2021-06-30","2021-06-30","2021-11-01","2021-11-02"), 
Category = c("FDE", "ABC", "FDE", "ABC"), 
coef = c(4, 1, 6, 1)), class = "data.frame",row.names = c(NA, -4L))


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                    br(),
                    tabPanel("",
                             sidebarLayout(
                               sidebarPanel(
                                 uiOutput('daterange'),
                                 br()
                                 
                               ),
                               mainPanel(
                                 dataTableOutput('table')

                               )
                             ))
  ))

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  data <- reactive(Test)
  
  output$daterange <- renderUI({
    dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Period you want to see:",
                   min = min(data()$date2),
                   max = max(data()$date2))
  })
  
  data_subset <- reactive({
    req(input$daterange1)
    req(input$daterange1[1] <= input$daterange1[2])
    days <- seq(input$daterange1[1], input$daterange1[2], by = 'day')
    subset(data(), date2 %in% days)
  })
  
 
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    data_subset()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `date2 %in% days`, the class of `days` is `Date` while the class of `date2` is `character`.
I suggest to modify first you data.frame to define your dates as actual dates:

```
Test <- structure(list(date2 = as.Date(c("2021-06-30","2021-06-30","2021-11-01","2021-11-02")), 
Category = c("FDE", "ABC", "FDE", "ABC"), 
coef = c(4, 1, 6, 1)), class = "data.frame",row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

and then to simply compare your dates.

```
    data_subset <- reactive({
        req(input$daterange1)
        req(input$daterange1[1] <= input$daterange1[2])
        subset(data(), date2 >= input$daterange1[1] & date2 <= input$daterange1[2])
)}
```

As for your second point, `dateRangeInput` provides, as a default the current date in the client's time zone... Hence, it is not NULL. You can alternatively add a button.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Regarding the first question OK, but regarding the second it is strange, because if I change, for example, instead of having 01/11 and 02/11 and inserting 01/10 and 02/10 in my database, the `daterange` works, that is, when I run the APP, the `daterange` is empty., but as my dates are for today and tomorrow, the `daterange` runs automatically instead empty. Is there no way to adjust this? that is, for it not to run automatically.

Comment: If the `start` and `end` dates are not in your range of dates (within `min` and `max`) than `daterange` is empty... but your calendar is empty too. If you like it like that, just use `start=Sys.time()+10000, end=Sys.time()+10000,` as parameters in your `dateRangInput`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I inserted this start and end that you mentioned in the answer, but the table is generated automatically anyway. When run APP, appears for day 01/11 in my `daterange`, but what I want is for it to be empty.

Comment: I will accept your answer, I did new question about the second question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69800521/how-to-adjust-daterange-in-shiny I think it's better for understand