# How to adjust daterange in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

The code below works normally. A table with information from my database called `Test`is displayed after choosing the start and end date of the `daterange`. So far OK. Notice that the table is not shown automatically when I run the APP, because I have the following: `req(input$daterange1)` in `data_subset` . However, if I change my `Test` database instead of having 01/10 and 02/10 and it has 01/11 and 02/11, when I run the APP, the table is automatically generated, do you know how to adjust this? That is, adjust so that `daterange` is empty too.

Executable code below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

Test <- structure(list(date2 = as.Date(c("2021-07-30","2021-07-30","2021-10-01","2021-10-02")), 
                       Category = c("FDE", "ABC", "FDE", "ABC"), 
                       coef = c(4, 1, 6, 1)), class = "data.frame",row.names = c(NA, -4L))


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                    br(),
                    tabPanel("",
                             sidebarLayout(
                               sidebarPanel(
                                 uiOutput('daterange'),
                                 br()
                                 
                               ),
                               mainPanel(
                                 dataTableOutput('table')

                               )
                             ))
  ))

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  data <- reactive(Test)
  
  output$daterange <- renderUI({
    dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Period you want to see:",
                   min   = min(data()$date2),
                   max   = max(data()$date2))
  })
  
  
  
  data_subset <- reactive({
    req(input$daterange1)
    req(input$daterange1[1] <= input$daterange1[2])
    days <- seq(input$daterange1[1], input$daterange1[2], by = 'day')
    subset(data(), date2 %in% days)
  })
  
 
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    data_subset()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

As it is, it works, I need to insert the start and end dates in `daterange` to generate the table.

[image]

If I use the database below:

```
Test <- structure(list(date2 = as.Date(c("2021-07-30","2021-07-30","2021-11-01","2021-11-02")), 
                       Category = c("FDE", "ABC", "FDE", "ABC"), 
                       coef = c(4, 1, 6, 1)), class = "data.frame",row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Notice that I only changed the days 01/10 and 02/10 to 01/11 and 02/11. When I run the code, the table is automatically generated as you can see below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are not using `start` and `end` in `dateRangeInput()`.  In this case both `start` and `end` are `NULL`. If your dataframe has current date (when you change 10/2 to 11/2), then both `start` and `end` get current date, hence you are noticing 11/1/21 as both start and end, and a table is displayed with current date info. My suggestion is that you should use `start` and `end` with `NA` in `updateDateRangeInput()`.  Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

Test <- structure(list(date2 = as.Date(c("2021-07-30","2021-07-30","2021-11-01","2021-11-02")),
                       Category = c("FDE", "ABC", "FDE", "ABC"),
                       coef = c(4, 1, 6, 1)), class = "data.frame",row.names = c(NA, -4L))

ui <- fluidPage(

  shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                    br(),
                    tabPanel("",
                             sidebarLayout(
                               sidebarPanel(
                                 uiOutput('daterange'),
                                 br()

                               ),
                               mainPanel(
                                 dataTableOutput('table')

                               )
                             ))
  ))

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  data <- reactive(Test)

  output$daterange <- renderUI({
    req(data())
    dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Period you want to see:",
                   min   = min(data()$date2),
                   max   = max(data()$date2)
                   )
  })
  
  observe({
    updateDateRangeInput(session, inputId = "daterange1", start = NA, end = NA)
  })

  data_subset <- reactive({
    req(input$daterange1)
    req(input$daterange1[1] <= input$daterange1[2])
    days <- seq(input$daterange1[1], input$daterange1[2], by = 'day')
    subset(data(), date2 %in% days)
  })

  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    data_subset()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks @YBS, however when I run your code, the table is automatically generated too. My idea is that the table is only generated when the user selects the `daterange` in Shiny.  I don't know if that's what you understood in the question above.

Comment: Please try the updated code.

Comment: Thank you so much @YBS, that's what I would like. I just want to clear a question: I inserted the  `observe({ updateDateRangeInput....` as you did, but in this case the file is loaded by `fileInput`, however it didn't work, do you know the reason or what I need to insert? I am using the code you did in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69669499/how-to-use-two-sheets-of-a-spreadsheet-in-shiny-code

Comment: Not sure what you are doing to not work.  Perhaps you can try `observeEvent(input$file, {...})`.  You can also post the full code in a new question so that I can take a look.